# Recursive Tcl procedure does not return anything

Tags: recursion, tcl

The following code is supposed to return factorial for a number given to the 
Tcl script as input parameter using a recursive procedure.

```
if {$argc !=1} {
        puts stderr "Error! ns called with wrong number of arguments! ($argc)"
        exit 1
} else {
        set f [lindex $argv 0]
}


proc Fact {x} {
        if { $x==1 } {
                return 1
        }
        return  $x * Fact ($x-1)
}
set res [Fact $f]
puts "Factorial of $f is $res"
```

But, it gives no output as shown below:
`$ tclsh fact.tcl  5
Factorial of 5 is`

I also tried `return [expr $x * Fact ($x-1)]` but it results in a parse error. I don't know if there is anything specific about recursive calls in Tcl that I miss.

Comment: try `return [expr {$x * [Fact [expr {$x-1}]}]`. I'll explain later why...

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, `return [expr {$x * [Fact [expr {$x-1}]]}]` worked, but this is syntax is kind of weird with so many brackets.

Comment: Tcl is not an language derived from algol syntax.  It doesn't look like other languages.

Answer (score 2):

Things get much tidier if you use the [`tcl::mathfunc`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm) namespace: then your procedure can be used inside `expr`

```
% proc ::tcl::mathfunc::fact {n} {
    expr {$n == 1 ? 1 : $n*fact($n-1)}
}
% fact 3
invalid command name "fact"
% expr {fact(3)}
6
% expr {fact(6)}
720
```

Comment: How about this: `proc func {name args body} {proc ::tcl::mathfunc::$name $args [list expr $body]}; func fact n {$n==1 ? 1 : $n*fact($n-1)}`…